# createIndex in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I remove items from my mongo database after an hour?

I've seen

```
db.Item.createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })
```

thrown around but how do i implement that in nodejs?

my db entries look like this

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5b4b64bc8c6e8add083431a3"
},
"location": {
    "lat": 59.924209956924315,
    "lng": 10.70636168616943
},
"name": "Richard Middleton",
"address": "Espresso House",
"message": "sdsd",
"createdAt": {
    "$date": "2018-07-15T15:14:04.573Z"
},
"updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2018-07-15T15:14:04.573Z"
},
```

I tried running it before my db.Item.find() for my get request but no luck.

Comment: Are you getting any error? and you need to put this `Item.createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })`  after your schema creation...

Comment: Hey mate yeah I saw someone doing that but got an error saying it wasn't a function, however I wasnt importing mongo or mongoose there. I found that I can add them directly in mlab. so sussed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase anyone comes across this, I was using mlab and in the database theres and indexes tab. i just added

```
{ "createdAt": 1 }
```

and selected TTL from the checkboxes and added my time in seconds.

Answer (score 30):

Two ways to create index. First

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let user = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true       //---Index----
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', user);
```

Second method

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let user = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
user.index({ email: 1 });    //---Index----
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', user);
```

When doing this if you are getting a warning(I am using MongoDB: 4.2.8 and Mongoose: 5.9.20)

```
DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
```

Then you might need to add 'useCreateIndex: true' to your mongoose.connect

```
mongoose.connect(Uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    useCreateIndex: true
});
```

Answer (score 10):

[**`createIndex`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) is a function for Mongodb.

In Mongoose it is renamed to [**`index`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

```
Item.index({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just been through this, and I would like to  highlight the exact solution:

Mongoose Schema:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const tokenSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    userId: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, expires: 30, default: Date.now }  // expires in 30 seconds
});
```

Important Note:
The `mongod` service runs once a minute, so it is possible that the record will not be deleted for close to a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so none of the other solutions worked for me (May 2021)

This code below did though. It involves setting the expireAt field to the actual time that you want it deleted, which makes sense really.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const YourSchema = new Schema({
 expireAt: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000   // expires in 10 minutes
 },
});
```

This is the only thing that worked, all the other solutions I tried always deleted after 1min, no matter the amount of time I added.